# Authenticate an ASP.NET MVC 5 app (targets .net 4.5) with an ASP.NET CORE 3 auth server that runs Identity Server 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, identityserver4, openid-connect

I'm currently building an auth server using Identity Server 4 with a spa (react) application that authenticates against it.  I would now like to also take another application that is in current existence (this is ASP.NET MVC 5, targets .NET 4.5, currently uses ASP.NET Identity 2 management classes for managing users and signout/sign in using cookie authentication) and update it so that it can log in externally with this new auth server (so a user can log in using the existing authentication, but also use this auth server now - so that a user session could be shared between this existing app and this other spa app).  The problem is as I understand it, that we need to use PKCE to authenticate with the auth server, but there doesn't appear to be a way to do this with the MVC 5 app - I can install the Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect package, but it doesn't allow for using PKCE since this is a newer thing (apparently if you target .net 4.6.1 there is a way to make that work with that version of the OpenIdConnect package).  I can't change our target, it needs to stay .NET 4.5 (to upgrade to 4.6.1 or higher would cause all kinds of problems with the build and current packages, it would be a larger undertaking than my organization is willing to take on at this time).  Is there a way that anyone knows of to make this work using an ASP.NET MVC 5 app that targets .NET 4.5 and an auth server that uses Identity Server 4?  Would the only way be to use a GrantType.Implcit flow instead of requiring PKCE with a GrantType.Code, and would that even be advised now?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you are dealing with 2 clients, spa app & ASP.NET MVC app, each client can have its own flow (grant type). We can use `authorization code flow` with `PKCE`, for the spa app. And `Implicit flow` for the ASP.NET MVC.

PKCE is suggested for interactive applications:

> a front-channel step via the browser where all “interactive” things happen, e.g. login page, consent etc. This step results in an authorization code that represents the outcome of the front-channel operation.
>
> a back-channel step where the authorization code from step 1 gets exchanged with the requested tokens. Confidential clients need to authenticate at this point.

The MVC app you described, is just doing authentication, then no worries it's fine to use implicit.

I have a post for implementing it [here](https://nahidfa.com/posts/identityserver4-and-asp-.net-mvc/)

Comment: This is great, looks like exactly what I needed.  I did try setting it up exactly as you have it, and it authenticates fine, but then the page gets stuck in some kind of redirection loop - it's constantly just going to the auth server to verify the user at http://localhost:5000/connect/authorize? right after verifying the user and sending them back.

Comment: My MVC app for cookie authentication has always used cookie authentication ( app.UseCookieAuthentication) with AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, not AuthenticationType = "Cookies" as you have in your example, so I kept using that for both app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication and app.UseCookieAuthentication ...so I wonder if I need to change both to "Cookies" now - I'm also wondering if I need some kind of endpoint that handles the response and signs them in with the cookie authentication too in the local app once it knows it's authenticated with the auth server.

Comment: 1. About `redirection loop`, do you have authorization in mvc? The default behaviour is to re-directs all unauthorized users to IdentityServer, this can cause infinite loop. you can change it by overriding `AuthorizeAttribute` - `HandleUnauthorizedRequest `. [here](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/07/09/identityserver-auth-mvc/)  is explained @user1368182

Comment: 2. For `AuthenticationType`, its just a string and will affect on the cookie name on mvc app, if you use `DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie` the cookie would be `.AspNet.ApplicationCookie`, but if you use `Cookies` the cookie name would be `.AspNet.Cookies`. BTW I suggest you to use `Cookies` as `DefaultAuthenticationTypes` is an enum on ` Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` which we dont use/need here @user1368182

Comment: 3. about custom endpoint, no there is no need for any endpoint, OWIN middleware handles it all - I suggest you to turn on the logs if its not yet to collect more details see [here](https://github.com/nahidf/IdentityServer4-adventures/blob/master/src/Net4MvcClient/Startup.cs#L35) for nlog sample @user1368182

Comment: Yes, I have Authorize attributes on my existing controllers - I'll try your suggestion.  I also need to be able to pass a parameter to the auth server endpoint so that when it redirects to login, it's in the query string or the return url's query string... to identify the id of a client in my application - so the identity/auth server is expecting that parameter to be in there.  Is there a way to add that?  I read that it can be done in RedirectToIdentityProvider on the options for UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication, but doesn't seem to be a property on those options anymore.

Comment: I figured out the parameter thing.  And the custom Authorize attribute works as you had recommended.  My only issue I think here now is how do I actually log the user in as a user in the mvc website?  The user in the identity server has the same email as the user account in the website, but they don't have the same user id/subid.  How do I map a user from the identity server to a user in the mvc website, and do I have to somehow load the user in the mvc site, based on a mapping from the user in the identity server and then call SignInAsync for that user?

Comment: you can use `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications.SecurityTokenValidated`, its invoked after security token is validated and `ClaimsIdentity` is generated. Code change on MVC app is like this: ```app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
 Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
 {
  SecurityTokenValidated = async n => {}
  RedirectToIdentityProvider = n => {}
        }
}``` sample [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/MVC%20Authentication/EmbeddedMvc/Startup.cs#L63) @user1368182

Comment: Ok, that's exactly what I needed - if I wanted to link accounts in the mvc app and identity server app - is there a typical flow to do that?  Say they log in to the identity server, then they go to the mvc app, and the mvc app has no knowledge of that other app yet, so it presents a login screen for its own app using the normal form/cookie auth, then the user logs in there and then the mvc app stores the identity server's user id with the user in the mvc app.  Would that be typical?

Comment: Looking up the user and calling SignInAsync in SecurityTokenValidated worked.  Also, oddly enough, I can no longer sign in using the regular login (so the mvc app's login page, not the identity server), when I change AuthenticationType to "Cookies" (instead of DefaultAuthenticationTypes.Cookie) in app.UseCookieAuthentication(...) - it forces going to the identity server login when not logged in ...I need to be able to use both types of logins going forward, because it's conceivable that we'll still have logins that won't use the identity server for auth.

Comment: This [doc](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/big_picture.html#how-identityserver4-can-help) shows how IDS can help and to me its best reference. my suggestion for ur case is to use ur old user-store in IDS instead of having 2 login process. but you should see what works the best for you. @user1368182